# How to check if file exist after build jlink?

Tags: java

I am trying to check if file exists in project. When I start my application through Intellij idea and check if file exists it's return true but when I create jlink build and start it through .bat and check if file exists it's always return false.

```
public class App {
    public static String getPathToDllTest(String filename) throws URISyntaxException {
        return Paths.get(App.class.getResource("files/" + filename + ".txt").toURI()).toString();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        File txt = new File(App.getPathToDllTest("test"));
        System.out.println(txt.exists());
    }
}
```

Here is basic Maven project resources structure I use:

```
src
  main
    java
      com
        example
          App.java
    resources
      com
        example
          files
            test.txt
```

Is there problem in path? How can I fix it?

Comment: is the `resources` folder inside of `src` (which is what it looks like but is wrong for a maven structure) or inside of `main` (what it should be)?

Comment: @f1sh After mvn:compile target package was created and contains App.class and folder(files/test.txt) in next structure(target->classes->com->example). And if I add line sout(new File(App.getPathToDllTest("test"))) and start .bat, I will get in console "\modules\Example\com\example\files\test.txt"

Comment: `App.class.getResource("files/" + filename + ".txt")` does not return a `file:` URI.  You *cannot* convert it to a Path or File, ever.  Instead of trying to make a file name out of it, just return the URL and read from it using [openStream](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/15/docs/api/java.base/java/net/URL.html#openStream()).

Comment: @VGR Thanks for your answer. openStream gives me opportunity read file data but I want to get true when use method exists(). And it is really return true when I starts my app in Intellij and always return false when I starts an App.bat file after building jlink

Comment: The URL will be null if the resource doesn’t exist.

Comment: @VGR I have changed return App.class.getResource("files/" + filename + ".txt"); know it returns URL and when I sout() gotten URL I see (jrt:/com.example/com/example/files/test.txt) but all the same returns false

Comment: What code returns false?

Comment: @VGR System.out.println(txt.exists());

Comment: **Do not use File or Path.**  test.txt is not a file.  It is data embedded inside your application.  To check whether it exists, check whether the URL is non-null.

Comment: jlink has a way to package native libraries during the jmod phase.  I don’t know if IntelliJ allows you to use that facility, though.  Another option is using [Files.copy](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/15/docs/api/java.base/java/nio/file/Files.html#copy(java.io.InputStream,java.nio.file.Path,java.nio.file.CopyOption...)) to copy the resource to an actual file, outside of your application.

Comment: @VGR I understood, thanks for your answers